# How to collect a map key-value into a list where value is a collection

Tags: java, lambda

Given the following map declaration `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>` I want to use Java 8 streams API to collect all the key-value pairs into a `List<Integer>` using a single stream iteration. For example, given the following mapping:

```
1->[2,3] 
4->[7,8]
```

The resulting list would be: `[1,2,3,4,7,8]`

Comment: Does it matter that map entries have undefined order?

Comment: @AndyTurner I need to get the keys into the list as well, not just the values.

Comment: I probably would do it imperative: `List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>(); map.forEach((key, value) -> res.add(key); res.addAll(value);});`

Comment: @Silverclaw order does not matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<Integer> list = map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(e -> Stream.concat(Stream.of(e.getKey()), e.getValue().stream()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```